# Cannot get the iframe element using contentDocument

Tags: iframe, youtube

Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.example.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to see the same youtube video on your browser???
If not then there is an issue with your browser settings. Or if you are doing this on any organisations machine then that URL can be blocked....
Can you post a piece of code to see how you are adding the Video link??